# Pauses between notes

Tags: rhythm, solfege

I am trying to make a microcontroller play simple "Christmas" melody and studying notes grammar just with this goal.

I got about notes durations, but handbook doesn't shed much light on pauses between notes.

There are 2 notations which sound the same for me and this doubts me:

- 2 disconnected Fa notes with duration 1/8
- 2 connected Fa notes with duration 1/8
- 1 Fa note with duration 1/4

What is the difference in performing notes above?
In pedals? In moments when release keys?

Another example is on the picture below [image]

Note Do is expressed in 2 odd parts. First 1/4 * 1.5 and 1/8.
1.5 is 1/8. So 3/8 and 1/8.
All these complications are definitely for expressing subtle pause. How to measure the pause?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would argue that the two separate notes don't imply a "subtle pause" that is measurable, but rather it means you play the same note twice. In most instruments, this will be audible as you will hear the attack again (i.e. the sound of the note beginning to play). If you are working with a [sound envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(music)) that doesn't have an attack (a pure sine wave, for instance) you may want to pause for a brief time to simulate that. You can play with it to see what sounds good, but any interruption in the sound will produce the desired effect.